# Auto setting time axis range in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a column chart which showing wrong dates :

[Here is the fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/5ft61jkq/2/)

```
data: [1432883717000,1432883717000,1433916917000]
```

All my timestamps belong to October 5th 2015, however the axis starts from 1970. Is there setting for enabling auto determination of time axis range?Is it possible to set point interval etc for this graph?

Comment: this usually means there is an error in your timestamps.  Often it is because you have passed epoch time in seconds, while javascript uses epoch time in milliseconds (timestamp * 1000).

Comment: but in the fiddle , it has date.UTC not timestamps. Agree with @jlbriggs to make change in timestamp

Comment: Yes, but the fiddle is just a highcharts sample and does not demonstrate the error.

Comment: Excellent catch by @jlbriggs

Comment: @jlbriggs sorry I pasted the wrong fiddle link. I have edited it now to show my jsfiddle link where the problem is reproduced.

Comment: Now that I see your actual data, two things: 1) the y axis starts at 1970, because that is zero, and a bar/column chart should *always* start at zero. If your data shouldn't start at zero, it shouldn't be a bar chart.  2) I am very confused as to what it is you are trying to show with your chart - can you elaborate on its purpose?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would solve this by using a dot plot instead of a column chart.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/96cz9gps/

Answer (score 0):

Set the min for the yAxis:

```
$(function () {
    var series1 = [1432883717000, 1432883717000, 1433916917000];
    var series2 = [null, 1433221380470, null];
    var min1 = Math.min.apply(null, series1);
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [800, 801, 802]
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: min1
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'due by time',
            data: series1
        }, {
            name: 'completed time',
            data: series2
        }

        ]

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ft61jkq/43/

Comment: thanks. So I have to determine the min value manually each time  the min value and assign it right?

Comment: Yes, there isn't an automatic "smallest in series" calculation, but calculating the min of an array is just  Math.min.apply(null, series);  See updated answer